# Excel - Best way to structure lists of lists?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, array

I have a sheet of cooking recipes. Each recipe has a name and a list of ingredients and their quantities. For example

```
Apple Pie
    x4 Apples
    x8 Flour
    x2 Butter
Scrambled Eggs
    x2 Eggs    
Burrito
    x1 Tortilla
    x1 Can of Beans
    x2 Cheese
    x1 Hot Sauce
```

At the moment I have the data organized like:

```
| ... | Apple Pie |   #   | Scrambled Eggs |   #   | ... |
| ... | Apples    |   4   | Eggs           |   2   | ... |
| ... | Flour     |   8   |                |       | ... |
| ... | Butter    |   2   |                |       | ... |
```

If I ever need to lookup what items a recipe has, I have to make a ton of calls like finding the column that say, `Apple Pie` is on. Then I have to determine how many ingredients are under `Apple Pie` by using `MATCH(ISBLANK`. Once I know that, then I have to do `INDEX(...):INDEX(...)` to grab the `Apples, Flour, Butter` and then I have to repeat ALL of that again to grab the quantities.

Is there a better way? In programming terms, I want to make a `Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>` where my recipe name is the *key* to my first map and the ingredient name is the *key* to my second map which yields the quantity for that ingredient.

I have another section of my sheet that has prices for each ingredient:

```
| Ingredient | Cost (Cents) |
| Apples     | 129          |
| Cheese     | 45           |
```

and I'd like to write a simple `SUM` function that would sum the cost for an `Apple Pie`, but the way I structured it makes the formula into a mess like:

`=IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(VLOOKUP(INDEX($F$4:$EQ$4, 1, MATCH($A3, $F$3:$EQ$3, 0)):INDEX($F$4:$EQ$11, MATCH(TRUE, ISBLANK(INDEX($F$4:$EQ$4, 1, MATCH($A3, $F$3:$EQ$3, 0)):INDEX($F$4:$EQ$11, 8, MATCH($A3, $F$3:$EQ$3, 0))), 0) - 1, MATCH($A3, $F$3:$EQ$3, 0)), 'PRICES'!$A:$G, 4, FALSE) * INDEX($F$4:$EQ$4, 1, MATCH($A3, $F$3:$EQ$3, 0) + 1):INDEX($F$4:$EQ$11, MATCH(TRUE, ISBLANK(INDEX($F$4:$EQ$4, 1, MATCH($A3, $F$3:$EQ$3, 0) + 1):INDEX($F$4:$EQ$11, 8, MATCH($A3, $F$3:$EQ$3, 0) + 1)), 0) - 1, MATCH($A3, $F$3:$EQ$3, 0) + 1))), "")`

What is a more ideal way to structure my data so that performing lookups of a three dimensional array such as this becomes easier?

Comment: This problem would seem better suited to a DB program like Access. And there are free recipe management templates available, although I have not tried any of them.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Unfortuantely I need an excel solution and this 'recipe' problem was just an example of something I need -- my data is not actually food recipes. However my data does resemble that same format.

Answer (score 2):

If you plan on using Excel to keep your recipes I would be more apt just to create a schedule like the one below.  That way you could select the recipe by typing in to you the search on the auto-filter drop down. I added cost columns at the end. You could then add a second small table with costs (which could be updated) and use a vlookup to add the costs.

[image]

[image]

I hope this help, Happy Holiday,
Brad

Comment: `use a vlookup to add the costs` How would you perform that step, since you have to VLOOKUP not one but all the ingredients of a recipe?

Answer (score 0):

to get the sum in one formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(I:I,H:H,INDEX(A:F,2,MATCH(M1,A1:F1,0)):INDEX(A:F,COUNTA(INDEX(A:F,MATCH(M1,A1:F1,0),0))-1,MATCH(M1,A1:F1,0)))*INDEX(A:F,2,MATCH(M1,A1:F1,0)+1):INDEX(A:F,COUNTA(INDEX(A:F,MATCH(M1,A1:F1,0),0))-1,MATCH(M1,A1:F1,0)+1))
```

This works in Excel, but will not work in Google Sheets.  You tagged it Excel, but the formula you provided is Google sheets.

[image]

Comment: Which part of this formula is not google sheets friendly?

Comment: As far as I understand it, you cannot use `INDEX():INDEX()` to denote a range like you can in Excel.  But I may be wrong.

Answer (score -1):

**:Caveat:**

*As per my understanding the below shown method is best possible I've discovered, using the shared data by OP, **where ingredients comes first, then the numbers in next column**.*

- I've decided to use single formula for both.
- Unable to find the clue all about adding X with numbers (like x4).

---

[image]

- Formula in cell `A107`:

  ```
   =IF(IFERROR(INDEX(A$100:A$103, ROWS(A107:A$107)), IFERROR(INDEX(C$100:C$101, ROWS(A107:A$107)-ROWS(A$100:A$103)), IFERROR(INDEX(E$100:E$104, ROWS(A107:A$107)-ROWS(A$100:A$103)-ROWS(C$100:C$101)), "")))=0,"",IFERROR(INDEX(A$100:A$103, ROWS(A107:A$107)), IFERROR(INDEX(C$100:C$101, ROWS(A107:A$107)-ROWS(A$100:A$103)), IFERROR(INDEX(E$100:E$104, ROWS(A107:A$107)-ROWS(A$100:A$103)-ROWS(C$100:C$101)), ""))))
  ```
- Fill formula right then down.

---

**N.B.**

*If you are stick with the shown output, where numbers prefixed with x comes first and next are the ingredients, then do the following.*

[image]

---

- Formula in cell `D107`:

  ```
   =IF(IFERROR(INDEX(B$100:B$103, ROWS(B$107:B107)),IFERROR(INDEX(D$100:D$101,ROWS(B$107:B107)-ROWS(B$100:B$103)),IFERROR(INDEX(F$100:F$104,ROWS(B$107:B107)-ROWS(B$100:B$103)-ROWS(D$100:D$101)),"")))=0,"","x"&IFERROR(INDEX(B$100:B$103,ROWS(B$107:B107)),IFERROR(INDEX(D$100:D$101,ROWS(B$107:B107)-ROWS(B$100:B$103)),IFERROR(INDEX(F$100:F$104,ROWS(B$107:B107)-ROWS(B$100:B$103)-ROWS(D$100:D$101)),""))))
  ```
- Formula in cell `E107`:

  ```
   =IFERROR(INDEX(A$100:A$103, ROWS(A107:A$107)), IFERROR(INDEX(C$100:C$101, ROWS(A107:A$107)-ROWS(A$100:A$103)), IFERROR(INDEX(E$100:E$104, ROWS(A107:A$107)-ROWS(A$100:A$103)-ROWS(C$100:C$101)), "")))
  ```
- Fill formula down.

---

***A***djust cell references in the formula as needed.

Comment: Please write your concern that Y this has been down voted !!